# How do I make my footer responsive straight (without any words breaking to the bottom line) on all devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, footer

I would like to know if there is a better way to make this footer responsive in a straight line (without any words breaking the line), on all devices without having to use media queries so often

I'm using the site inspector to help me define responsiveness, but it's indicating that every few pixels I should reset the side paddings again,

Is this right or is there a better way to make it straight and responsive for all devices?

Thanks for the help!

```css
.footerTp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 2rem 32%;
}

.footer-textTp p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 1335px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 34%;
  }
  .footer-textTp p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1315px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1240px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 32%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1170px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 31%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1110px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 30%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1055px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 28%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 27%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 26%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 882px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 847px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 24%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 815px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 23%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 786px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 22%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 758px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 21%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 732px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 20%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 709px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 19%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 687px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 18%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 17%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 647px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 16%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 627px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 15%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 609px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 14%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 595px) {
  .footerTp {
    padding: 2rem 13%;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="footerTp">
  <div class="footer-textTp">
    <p>
      Copyright &copy; 2023 by Palace of Triumph | All Rights Reserved
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Padding is a terrible method of positioning. Perhaps research alternative layout methods such as flexbox or Css-grid

Comment: That's the wildest way I've ever seen `text-align: center` spelled

Comment: Hello @isherwood, in the horizontal position it means that I want the entire sentence to be in a straight line without any words on the bottom line like reserved for example and not just centering the text is not working so I am using padding.

Comment: You're still not clear. The text doesn't wrap until very small sizes even with _no_ styles, and reducing font is the only way to remedy that. Tiny fonts aren't readable, though.

Comment: To be specific, the text doesn't wrap until 488px with the padding you have in place and 365px with no padding. Why do you have all those media queries for much larger sizes?

Comment: @WashingtonRockets on larger screens, that copyright line shouldn't be wrapping, unless there are other elements around, affecting it. Is your <footer> code that you posted the full code?

Comment: @isherwood here for me it is breaking above 488px several times, I realize based on previous experiences that there is a difference between the tests carried out based on the stackoverflow code tester and what is actually happening, would you like to have access to the demo site link? (if this is the case, I will cancel these definitions I made so that you can better understand the problem)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent words breaking, a simple CSS code of
`white-space: nowrap;` would do the trick.

```css
footer {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    Copyright &copy; 2023 by Palace of Triumph | All Rights Reserved
</footer>
```

It should be noted that on smaller width screens, this would cut off the text and the user will not see the rest.
In some cases, the user may not even be able to scroll horizontally to see the content, but this problem is unrelated to this answer.

---

#### This section was posted before OP edited

If you know you want to have an element be responsive on all sizes, then it is easiest to build from the smallest size, and then set media queries as the screen is larger. With media queries, figure out your breakpoints between sizes. At what width size, should the element change?

With your example code, you have a LOT of breakpoints, 21 in fact. Are they all necessary? Can you cut down on this?

The better approach is to just let a framework do the work for you. That way, you will not need to define your own breakpoints, and you only need to worry about content.

This does not mean a framework will always solve all of your problems, but most of the time, it makes a lot of things easier.

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is a popular framework, if you only want something for CSS.

Comment: Hi @eager-to-Learn ok but how could this footer be straight (without any word breaking the line) on all devices with bootstrap

Comment: @WashingtonRockets Without *any* styling, a string of words will wrap to stay on the screen. You can use CSS to style it so it will never ever wrap, but it *could* make content go off screen. This does not require bootstrap.

Comment: hello @eager-to-learn thanks for your effort in helping me, I tested it here and it works up to 750px, maybe this way I don't have to define so many media queries, but rather start defining when it is no longer visible to the user, a question I could use this definition to make h1, h2, h3, p responsive also up to a certain width?